# How do I create an if statement to see if a user has entered a specific word (Java)

Tags: java

So I'm currently learning Java & have been watching thenewboston but I'm wanting to see if what the user types is x then do x hopefully that makes sense.

If you could leave an example it would help me a lot.

Comment: Have you tried google?

Comment: Please be more specific with your question. If you want to find out more about the fundamentals of java, a tutorial might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `string1.equals(string2)` method:

```
String expected = "hello, world";
if(input.equals(expected)){
    //Do something
}
```

This method returns true if the two strings are equal and false if they are not. You cannot just use `==` as this compares the pointers/references of the strings, and not the strings' content.

Edit: You can read input by using a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).